# Why can't acess .properties file when running on Apache Tomcat Server?

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, path, jersey

So I have a problem: I have a `Java` project that connects to a `DB` and has some logic then answers via a `RESTful Webservice` request.

The thing is the connection do my DB was fixed (only connected to one `DB`) and hard to change because in the end I create a `.war` file, so for someone to use the .war it had to use the same `DB` connection settings and names.

Therefore I created a `.properties` file inside `WebContent/WEB-INF/` (so the path is `WebContent/WEB-INF/config.properties`). When I run the project locally it works fine, the minute I run it on the `Apache Tomcat Server` it says he can't find the path specified, thus the `NullPointerException`.

Would appreciate if someone could shed some light on the issue. Thanks to all.

PS: Sorry for mispelling and bad formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a WAR the path of all the files are set relative to the context root (though in actual file system you can still figure it out in tomcat/jboss etc. it is not recommended to access files that way). The files can be got hold of through standard getResourceAsStream with relative path to the files /WEB-INF/config.properies